# Firebase Server communication

Tags: c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iot, esp8266

Is it Possible to upload values to firebase cloud via esp8266 from embedded c code ! My intention is , to upload sensor values which should communicate directly with firebase server ! In the code I am giving the firebase host server with database Secrets as API key ! are the details alone needed to communicate with firebase?

[image]

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include "uart.h"
#include"adc.h"

void main()
{
DDRB=0b11111111;
PORTB=0b11111111;
unsigned char digital;
uart_init();
adc_init();
_delay_ms(1000);
uart_string("AT+CWMODE=3\r\n");  \\MODE SELECT
_delay_ms(3000);


uart_string("AT+CWJAP=\"HOTSPOT NAME\",\"PWD\"\r\n");  \\WIFI PWD AND USERNAME
_delay_ms(5000);
_delay_ms(5000);
_delay_ms(5000);
while(1)
{
digital=getdata(0);   \\READ LDR VALUE

uart_string("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"feelXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com\",80\r\n"); \\CONNECT WITH THINKSPEAK CLOUD
_delay_ms(3000);


uart_string("AT+CIPSEND=51\r\n");  \\TOTAL NO OF CHARACTER TO BE SEND IN BELOW LINK(NOT GREATER THAN OR LESS THAN THE ACTUAL VALUE)(CORRECT VALUE SHLD BE MENTIONED)
_delay_ms(100);

uart_string("GET /update?api_key=API KEY`enter code here`&field1=");   \\TYPE API WRITE KEY 
uart_num(digital);
uart_string("\r\n");
_delay_ms(100);`enter code here`


uart_string("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n");   \\CLOSE
_delay_ms(6000);


}
}
```